# SDL configuration in Eclipse IDE

Tags: linux, eclipse, opengl, sdl

I am trying to get a OpenGL code run on Eclipse in Linux x86 environment (ubuntu): 
   http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/vertex_buffer_objects/22002/
The code would run properly after I input in the command line with

> g++ main.cpp error.cpp lesson45.cpp -o lesson45 -L/usr/X11R6/lib/ -lGL -lGLU `sdl-config --cflags --libs`

Which is the instruction from the make file.
Now I'm attempting to get the code run on Eclipse, I know I must set up linker libraries GL and GLU and linker library directory /usr/X11R6/lib/. However, with respect to `sdl-config --cflags --libs`, I am not sure how to configure it within Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new C++ project (File > New > C++ Project). You will need to pick a toolchain - Linux GCC.

If you want to use C++11 do the following:

1. Right click your Project under “Package Explorer” and select Properties.
2. Select (C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC C++ Compiler > Miscellaneous)
3. Under “Other flags” add: -std=c++0x
4. Click Apply then OK

Configure Eclipse to use SDL2

1. Right click your Project under “Package Explorer” and select Properties.
2. Select (C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Libraries)
3. Click “Add” and add “SDL2″ and click OK
4. Click “Add” and add “SDL2main” and click OK

This process has been tested and confirmed working although I don't take any credit for it. Information sourced from [HERE](http://zxiiro.wordpress.com/2013/08/08/setting-up-eclipse-cdt-for-sdl2-development/)

Answer (score 2):

In case you cannot find anything more civilized to configure Eclipse, you can always extract this information from the `sdl-config` invocation and configure the settings by hand:

```
## Compiler flags
$ sdl-config  --cflags
-I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT

## Linker flags
$ sdl-config  --libs
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll attempt to provide a more thorough answer from a combination of the previously given suggestions.  On a Fedora22 system with Eclipse Mars version 4.5.1 this worked for me.  As suggested by @Zammalad, with a few changes, first

- Create a new C++ project (***File > New > C++ Project***).
- You will need to pick a toolchain - ***Linux GCC***.

### If you want to use C++11 do the following:

- Right click your Project under “Package Explorer” and select ***Properties***.
- Select (***C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC C++ Compiler > Dialect***)
- Under “***Language standard***” select: "*ISO C++11 (-std=c++0x)*". Click Apply, then OK.

### Configure Eclipse to use SDL2

At this step, I'd suggest taking @esperanto's approach to use the system's terminal/shell to find out or verify the existence/location of the necessary files/libraries for SDL2 on your system.

First, if you want to find the location of the necessary libraries on your system, executing the following in the terminal will provide you with the "include" location and other compiler/preprocessor flags

```
$ sdl2-config --cflags
```

Similarly, to list the libraries/linker-flags

```
$ sdl2-config --libs
```

For example, on my Fedora22 (64bit) system, the output looks like this

```
$ sdl2-config --cflags --libs
-I/usr/include/SDL2 -D_REENTRANT
-lSDL2 -lpthread
```

You can test the compilation in a separate temporary directory without the eclipse-related project files--i.e. only the source files--like this:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/testing
$ cp -r main.cpp error.cpp lesson45.cpp /tmp/testing/.
$ cd /tmp/testing
$ g++ `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -o lesson45 main.cpp error.cpp lesson45.cpp
```

---

Now, to use the SDL2 libraries/paths within Eclipse, add the necessary libraries from the `sdl2-config --libs` output

- Right click your Project under “Package Explorer” and select ***Properties***.
- Select (***C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Libraries***)
- Click “***Add***” and type `SDL2` and click OK
- Click “***Add***” and type `pthread` and click OK

To add the preprocessor directive from the `sdl2-config --cflags` output

- Right click your Project under “Package Explorer” and select ***Properties***.
- Select (***C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC C++ Compiler > Preprocessor**)
- Under "***Defined symbols (-D)***", Click the "Add" icon
- Type `_REENTRANT` and click OK